# Getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException in JDK11

Tags: java, encryption, sslhandshakeexception

I am setting up my web application in JDK11 runtime environment. I am able to bring my application server up in JDK8 runtime enviroment but getting below exception after switching to JDK11 enviroment.

Exception : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Invalid ECDH ServerKeyExchange signature

For SSlHandshake I am using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 cipher suite Algorithm. 
I am suspecting that this algorithm is not supported by JDK11(https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8209965). I am stucked at this point on migrating my application. 
Kindly help me regarding this.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to use certificate inside java/jre/lib/security if it exists in JDK-11.

Comment: The bug you're pointing to should only happen when connecting to faulty, non Java *servers* so I don't think it is applicable. This could also be a problem (bug or misconfiguration) in your client application. Please always show complete stacktraces.

Comment: @Sambit I had added it but it wasn't working.
It was due to client configuration.

Comment: Great, I'll cover my crystal ball with a black blanket again then :P

Comment: @MaartenBodewes haha Yeah Now You Can :)